# My donut base looks really bright

Tags: rendering, shaders, texture-painting

I was following the Blender Guru Donut Tutorial, and I ran into an issue during shading or texture paint and now my donut base looks really bright!

[image]
[image: here is what it looks like in layout]

Comment: If you can see in your image, you have the mix node directly connected to the material output (Skipping the principled BSDF) - this gives unshaded outputs that are "fully bright". To get the correct lighting and shadows, connect the Principled BSDF back up again.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett This is an answer, not a comment. Please post it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I didn't notice that at first, I appreciate it.